What does the $F$ in Newton's second law equation mean?
This is a super simple question: does $F$ represent the net force exerted on an object or the force it exerts on another object as a result of momentum? Say a ball is rolling. In this specific instance, if we wrote in equation in the format $F=ma$, would $F$ be the net force acting on it and causing its movement? Or, would F be the force that the ball would exert on another object when it hits it, such as a wall (in this case, I am assuming as mass and acceleration increase, so does momentum, meaning the ball strikes another object with more force)? My teacher was unclear about this, so I am a little confused.

In $ \vec{a} = \vec{F}_{\textrm{net}}/m$, the acceleration is the acceleration of the obejct, the force is the sum of all the forces acting on the object, and $m$ is the object's mass. This should be clear from your textbook, so consult that too!

"would F be the force that the ball would exert on another object when it hits it, such as a wall" Why do you think so? Don't make things up yourself. The $F$ in $F=ma$ is the net force. It  isn't difficult to find this out. Have you even done any basic research? Please clarify.

Really don't understand the down votes or closure votes. One would think a new learner to the subject should be encouraged to ask basic conceptual questions here

@RC_23 The question is unclear and lacks basic research. See my comment above.

I have done basic research on the topic, but there are several sources that we have been consulting for homework assignments that suggest the above statement. I did consult my textbook and other sources, but it has been difficult to find a clear answer, especially when the answer seems unclear even in class. I am basing my question a comment made several times in class during the lesson.

"several sources that we have been consulting" Then please include them into your question so that answers can address them. We can't read your mind. Anyway, $F$ in $F=ma$ only has one meaning and that is the net force. This is a fundamental definition in Newtonian mechanics. The entire question of why you think this is unclear and why you think there is some other meaning is beyond me.

To be clear, I am also in middle school and we have only begun learning this concept this year. One of the sources is my teacher and classmates, and the other is an assignment on Stemscopes called revolving around Newton's laws and rollercoasters. I'll try to find the link. Please understand that I am completely new to this topic and it's difficult to differentiate between correct and incorrect statements online.

By Newton's Reckoning, a force was a push or a pull. At first it probably meant anything that caused change in an object's momentum. How do you unify the effects of a spring pulling on an object, vs, tension holding it up, vs the effects of gravity? Newton figured out how to measure all those forces in a uniform way, so that spring pulls with 5N, gravity pulls that 1 kilogram mass with 9.8N.  Get the same pull from a spring and see that it causes twice the acceleration on an object with half the mass.

Thanks for the answers and reopening the question! This makes a lot of sense.

@user386598 In Newtonian mechanics we model objects as being acted upon by forces. Forces are modeled as vectors. The $F$ represents the sum of all forces acting on the object. That's it. Forces acting on other objects are not included in the sum.

The acceleration of an object only depends on the forces acting upon that object. Imagine a ball falling down and hitting the floor. There are two forces due to the impact: the force on the ball from the floor, and the force on the floor from the ball. The only force that matters for determing how the ball will move is the first one. The force on the floor due to the ball does not affect the ball.
When using $F=ma$ to study an object, $F$ is the total force on that object, $m$ is the mass of that object, and $a$ is the acceleration of that object. Now, the forces that sum to $F$ on an object may come from other objects (walls, ropes, people pushing), but they only matter for what they do to the object in question.

Of course, the latter of those two forces usually gets neglected because the acceleration on the floor due to a force impressed by a falling ball is usually small (barring an exceptionally large ball).

The force in the equation $\vec F = m \vec a$ is the force acting on the body of mass $m$ and whose acceleration is $\vec a$.
It is important to avoid two possible sources of confusion.

Even though the third principle states that the force of a body $1$ on a body $2$ and the force of a body $2$ on a body $1$ are equal and have opposite directions, the $\vec F$ appearing in the second law is the net force resulting from the vector sum of the forces on the body of mass $m$ due to all the other bodies. As such, if there is more than one body acting on the mass $m$, applying the third principle to the net force $\vec F$ is meaningless
Some confusion could also originate from the conceptual approach that uses the second law as a force definition. Since $\vec a$ is the acceleration of the body of mass $m$, it could be possible to think that $\vec F$ should also be a quantity associated with the same body, interpreting it as the force exerted on another body. This is not the case, mainly for the same reason as the previous one.
.


The Newton's 2nd law, $F=ma$, the $F$ is the net force exerted on the object that experiences the acceleration $a$.
The 2nd law only involves one object (or one system). The force and the acceleration that this object (system) experiences, and the mass that this object (system) has.
This law does not tell anything about interaction with other objects (or other systems). For that, you will have to look at Newton's 3rd law of motion.
